# Integral of a vector function

Tags: integration, multiple-integral

I would like to compute the an integral of a function that takes in a vector, but got stuck. Would anyone tell me how to compute it?

Let $\boldsymbol{x}$ be a vector as below.

$$
\boldsymbol{x} = [x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}]^{T}
$$

Integral $I$ is given by the following equation with $i,j=1 \cdots n$, and $p\in\mathbb{R}$
$$I=\int_{\mathbb R^n}(1+||x||^{2})^{-p}x_{i}x_{j}\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{x}$$

Comment: The integral has the product of two of the $n$ coordinates, but it is not specified which. We want to do it for each possible pair $i,j$? Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, $i$ and $j$ can be anything in $[1,n]$. I tried it in a low dimension and it seems that $I=0$ if $i \neq j$, but cannot generalize it.

Comment: Are you integrating over all of $\Bbb R^n$? You notation is certainly not clear. For starters, you need $p>1+n/2$ for the integral to converge. Then provided $i\ne j$, you will get $0$ by symmetry. For $i=j$, you will want to use spherical coordinates and you get a standard integral.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this area. I believe that I am integrating over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. For $p$, please assume that it satisfy the condition you mentioned. Is the requirement comes from the fact that arguments of beta function is positive?

Comment: Nothing to do with beta functions. Just the fact that in spherical coordinates you will get $$\int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}\cdot r^2}{(1+r^2)^p}\,dr$$ and you need a net power less than $-1$ of $r$ for the integral to converge. (I'm ignoring the trigonometric factor which needs to be there for $x_ix_j$.)

Comment: Okay, I tried to compute it using Beta function, but thank you anyway.
Oh, the trigonometric part is orthogonal the integral is $0$ if $i \neq j$) and thus I can argue that my results in the low dimension can be generalized to $n$ dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us consider the more general case $$T_{ij}:=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\! d^nx \, x_i x_j \,  f(\Vert x \Vert), $$ with an arbitrary function $f$ such that the integrals exist. For any ${\rm SO}(n)$ matrix $R$ ($R^TR=R R^T=\mathbf{1}_n, \, \det R =1$), the relation $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^n R_{ik} R_{j\ell} T_{k\ell}=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\! d^n x \, (R x)_i(Rx)_j \, f(\Vert x \Vert) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \! d^n y \, y_i y_j \, f(\Vert y\Vert)=T_{ij}$$ holds, where the variable transformation $y=Rx$ together with $\det R =1$ and $\Vert Rx \Vert =\Vert x \Vert$ was performed. Written in matrix notation, we have found $$ R T R^T=R \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad R T =TR,$$ i.e. $T$ commutes with all elements of ${\rm SO}(n)$ and Schur tells us that $T$ must be proportional to the unit matrix, $ T= \lambda \mathbf{1}_n$. Taking the trace, we find $$\lambda = \frac{1}{n}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\! d^nx \, \Vert x \Vert ^2 f(\Vert x \Vert) =\frac{V_{{\rm S}^{n-1}}}{n} \int\limits_0^\infty\! dr \, r^{n-1}  r^2 f(r), $$ where $V_{{\rm S}^{n-1}}=2 \pi^{n/2}/\Gamma(n/2)$ is the volume of the $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere ${\rm S}^{n-1}$, giving the final result $$ T_{ij}=    \frac{ 2 \pi^{n/2}\delta_{ij}}{n \, \Gamma(n/2)} \int\limits_0^\infty \! dr \, r^{n+1} f(r).$$ The further steps for the special case $f(r)=(1+r^2)^{-p}$ (with $p> 1+n/2$) are left as an exercise.